# How can I limit number of suggestions when using YouCompleteMe?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me

I'm working on fairly large php codebase (~1.3 mil lines of code). I have generated tags and now when I'm typing something like

```
$data->
```

YouCompleteMe lags really hard and basically freezes Vim when trying to fetch list of all possible completions from tags. Is there a way to fix this? For example by limiting number of suggestions, e.g. displaying only 10 top suggestions instead of loading whole list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not you display all of the suggestions probably won't affect the lag. YouCompleteMe will search through all of the possible completions anyway. There is no way to display the "10 top suggestions" without having considered all possible suggestions - at least with the way YCM works.

If you still want to, `pumheight` sets the menu height.